# How to get the ID of a Img by the image-path?

Tags: jquery

I've a simple question. I look around but I couldn't find a answer for that.

If I have a lot of simple image-tag with different images, and different ids.

```html
<img scr="mypathtoimgae" id="1234">
```

Now i want to access one of these image to change the attributes. For that I need a way to get access to the specific image, but I only know the image-path (scr).

How can I get the id of the image if I only know the "mypathtoimage"?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fairly straight-forward when you know the `img` src. You can use the attribute selectors and get the information:

```js
$(function () {
  var imgSrc = "praveen.png";
  console.log($('[src="' + imgSrc + '"]').get(0).id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="google" src="google.png" />
<img id="praveen" src="praveen.png" />
<img id="microsoft" src="microsoft.png" />
```

The thing I do above is, get the pure DOM element and try to get the `id` property of it. All the elements have an `id` property that exposes their `id` attribute.

You can also do it using pure JavaScript:

```js
var imgSrc = "praveen.png";
console.log(document.querySelector('[src="' + imgSrc + '"]').id);
```

```html
<img id="google" src="google.png" />
<img id="praveen" src="praveen.png" />
<img id="microsoft" src="microsoft.png" />
```